# Tkinter Button not resizing correctly according to the font size on a Mac

Tags: python, tkinter

As you can see, I have some code here that creates a button with font that is size 48pt and is bold.

```
from tkinter import *
win = Tk()
button = Button(win, text="Play", font=("Helvetica 48 bold"))
button.pack()
win.mainloop()
```

However, when I run the code, the button isn't the right size. It resizes its width correctly, but for some reason the enlarged font stretches beyond the top and bottom limits of the button. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: This is might be a platform specific problem, because your code works perfectly for me (except for a missing `)`). Are you using a Linux distribution?

Comment: OS X.  Why do people assume Linux over Mac?  Is it really that bad for programming?

Comment: OS X is perfectly fine :) I was asking because I have not the problem on my Mac, and since on Windows this kind of problems I have never had, I thought it could be because of some Linux distribution..

Comment: Ah.  I've seen a few places that Macs are suboptimal when it comes to programming, but I have a good friend who's a developer and he just got a mac.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem since it works fine for me, but have you tried the `expand` and `fill` attributes of `pack`? If they don't work you could also use `ipady` to enlarge the button, but that will give too large buttons on other operating systems. More info on the `pack` method and its options [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem unique to OSX -- OSX buttons really want to look like OSX buttons, and aren't nearly as configurable as they are on other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

This code will run as intended on Windows 8.1 with Python 3 (it did for me).

Perhaps a typo as well, but you need to add an ending ')' to this line:

```
button = Button(win, text="Play", font=("Helvetica 48 bold")
```

Comment: I'm on OS X, forgot to mention that.

Comment: @DrewNolan Strange. I am also using an OS X, and this problem does not exist.

Comment: Huh.  Weird.  I have 10.10.1.  Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: @DrewNolan Try to update to the 10.10.2 version. That could be the problem.

Comment: @Rinzler Just did, same problem.

Comment: @DrewNolan Which Tcl/Tk version are you using? You can simply import `tkinter` in the interactive shell and then you can do `tkinter.TclVersion` and `tkinter.TkVersion`

Comment: @Rinzler I have Tcl 8.6, which I installed yesterday.

Comment: @DrewNolan I am still using the 8.5 Tk version, so that could be the problem

Comment: @Rinzler probably.  I'll just make do with puny buttons for now, thanks for the help!